# iOS: Disable UITableView animation when keyboard shows up

Tags: ios, uitableview, keyboard, uitextview, becomefirstresponder

Everyone wants to move the UITableView when the keyboard pops up, but I'm looking for a way to disable the automatic animation to the cursor when the keyboard pops up. I'm experiencing an odd jerking / jolting / erratic scrolling behavior when the keyboard pops up and causes the UITableView to scroll to the cursor (to avoid blocking it).

Each of my UITableView cells has a UITextView in it. I don't commit any other animations when the keyboard pops up.

At this point, I would like to disable the animation completely and manually scroll to a desired CGPoint.

Thank you!

Comment: I have a 3 line text field in a cell. I want to be able to add a cell to the table, shrink the table to the height it should be when the keyboard is presented and then have the table view be scrolled all the way to the bottom. I currently have a intermittent solution where I get a notification for keyboardWillShow and perform a .2 second animation shrinking the tableview height and on completion do a 0.05 second delayed request to have the tableview scroll all the way to the bottom. Works in some cases depending on cell count. Just need first responder not to scroll the table. HELP!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem? I am experiencing the exact same thing where my tableview resizes properly, but performs this weird jumping at the end.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The automatic scrolling code resides in tableViewController, so auto-scrolling can't be disabled. Instead of subclassing from UITableViewController you can subclass from UIViewController and use a tableView inside it.
If you are willing to use UITableViewController itself, you can override viewWillAppear and don't call [super viewWillAppear].

Comment: For anyone else searching for this problem and coming across this answer, please be cautious doing this. It may be the only thing that seems achievable and easy, but it's never a good idea not calling super within a view lifecycle method such as `viewWillAppear`