# How to prevent UITextView from moving up on keyboard show

Tags: ios

I have a `UITableViewController` and `UITextView` in one of the cells. 
When a user taps on `UITextView` all the table moves up `tableView.frame.origin.y = -88`. 
As far as I can tell `UITableViewController` forces the table to move up. Is there a way to prevent this kind of behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot disable autoscrolling on the UITableViewController.
The best thing to do would probably be to use a UIViewController as a table view's delegate and datasource. Check this answer out.

[iOS: Disable UITableView animation when keyboard shows up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10040508/ios-disable-uitableview-animation-when-keyboard-shows-up)

Answer (score 0):

Just use a `UIViewController` instead of a `UITableViewController` - and make sure it conforms to `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDatasource` protocols.

Comment: I have a static table made in Xcode UIBuilder. When I try to change from UITableViewController to UIViewController my application crash with error:  
>Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<newMessageViewController 0x75ea930> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key staticDataSource.'

Comment: Ah, you're using static cells in a Storyboard... I'm not sure if this will work then.