# UITableViewCell Objects Are Misplaced When Being Rendered For the First Time

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, animation

As many of you may have noticed, sometimes when UITableView is changing height and therefore showing new rows, contents of those rows are misplaced ( like when they are all located at the center of the row or the most left part of the row or etc. ) and when the row displays, they immediately move (animatedly) to their correct and original location. Can anyone tell how can I disable this kind of animation ?

Thank you

---

P.S: I know that my description is not quite clear, so I have recorded a video to illustrate what's going on and it can be access from [this link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-cb_GWOkXD-X1hSWlRKT1A2VWs/edit?usp=sharing). ( LINK UPDATED )

P.P.S: This can be seen in other messaging apps like `Viber` and `Whatsapp` too. I have recorded same effect's video from `Viber` and `Whatsapp`, but there must be a solution to disable it and that's apparently what `Line` has done.

Comment: In your UITableView delegate method "CellForRowAtIndex....", comment the if (cell==nil){ }

Like remove this two line code, --> "if(cell == nil){" and "}"

Comment: Have you tried this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10040508/ios-disable-uitableview-animation-when-keyboard-shows-up ?

Comment: Dear radical, I can't get how does it relate it to my question

Comment: @akk I did that and no progress :(

Comment: @Unkn0wn.Bit the same problem occur to me, i fixed this same.

Answer (score 0):

This one is work for me.Ex- when row data is come First time then it display with animation.

//This function is where all the magic happens - Called beside rowForCellAtIndexPath

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
if(![arrObjectsDone containsObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row]])
{
    cell.frame = CGRectMake(640, cell.frame.origin.y, cell.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height);
    [arrObjectsDone addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row]];
}
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"rotation" context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
    cell.frame = CGRectMake(0, cell.frame.origin.y, cell.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height);
    [UIView commitAnimations];   
}
```

Comment: I think you didn't quite get me ! This animating thing is perform by OS by default, And I want to disable it !